# I am trying to voice for ACX audiobooks and I am 14, is there an age limit?

Tags: publishing

How old would I have to be? Would I be able to get a fair pay for my age? What roles would I be able to voice?

Comment: It's not really a writing question as such.

Answer (score 2):

From https://help.acx.com/s/article/how-old-does-one-have-to-be-to-use-acx

> To open an account on ACX, you must be at least 18 years old or the legal age of majority in the jurisdiction in which you reside. ACX is currently open to residents of the United States, United Kingdom, Canada and Ireland who have a mailing address, valid local Taxpayer Identification Number (TIN), and banking details for one of these countries. We hope to open up to a wider global audience in the future.
>
> For more information, please refer to section 4 of the ACX Account Holder Agreement: http://www.acx.com/help/account-holder-agreement/201481940

So at 14 you won't be allowed to have an account at ACX, and consequently can't use their website and tools to offer your services as narrator.